# Applying linearity of a differential operator to solve ODE

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, taylor-expansion

I'm attempting to solve the following ODE:

$$xy''+y'-y=0$$

According to Frobenius' theorem, there exists a solution to this ODE in the form of a series given by the linear combination of two solutions such that: $y=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$, where:

$$y_1=\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$y_2=y_1log|x|+\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n$$

My issue is not how to solve the ODE, I've already managed to do it, but rather how to find the second solution, $y_2$, in a more elegant way instead of deriving the expression twice, substituting the series in the equation and identifying a pattern for the general term of the sum. In order to do this, following my professor's advice, I have defined the differential operator:

$$L=x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{d}{dx}-1$$

where, of course, $L[y_1]=L[y_2]=0$ since they are both solutions to my equation. Applying this operator on the second solution, I get:

$$L[y_2]=L[y_1]log|x|+y_1L[log|x|]+L[u_2]=0$$

Since the first term is null, then i end up with:

$$y_1L[log|x|]+L[u_2]=0$$

and from here I get:

$$-y_1+L[u_2]=0$$

although, according to the calculations I did earlier, before using operators, what I should really obtain is:

$$2y_1'+L[u_2]=0$$

Why is this? I'm assuming it is because I'm considering my operator is linear when it really isn't, although I don't quite understand why it wouldn't be, since it fullfils the basic properties of linearity.

Comment: Also, are you asking where $y_2=y_1\log|x|+u_2$ comes from or rather if there's another way to directly find $y_2$?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. not at all, I understand Frobeniu's theorem. My question is why the two calculations I have written don't yield the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used product rule as though the linear differential operator was a first order differential operator:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal L[u\cdot v]&=\left(x\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}-1\right)[u\cdot v]\\
&=x\frac{\mathrm d^2(u\cdot v)}{\mathrm dx^2}+\frac{\mathrm d(u\cdot v)}{\mathrm dx}-uv\\
&=x\left(v\frac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dx^2}+2\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+u\frac{\mathrm d^2v}{\mathrm dx^2}\right)+v\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}+u\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}-uv\\
&=v\left(x\frac{\mathrm d^2u}{\mathrm dx^2}+\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}-u\right)+u\left(x\frac{\mathrm d^2v}{\mathrm dx^2}+\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}-v\right)+2x\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+uv\\
&=v\mathcal L[u]+u\mathcal L[v]+2x\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+uv\neq v\mathcal L[u]+u\mathcal L[v]
\end{align}$$
Substituting $u=y_1$ and $v=\log|x|$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal L[y_1\log|x|]&=\log|x|\overbrace{\mathcal L[y_1]}^0+y_1\mathcal L[\log|x|]+2x\frac{\mathrm dy_1}{\mathrm dx}\overbrace{\frac{\mathrm d\log|x|}{\mathrm dx}}^{1/x}+y_1\log|x|\\
&=y_1\mathcal L[\log|x|]+2y_1'+y_1\log|x|\\
&=y_1\left(x\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm d^2\log|x|}{\mathrm dx^2}}_{-1/x^2}+\underbrace{\frac{\mathrm d\log|x|}{\mathrm dx}}_{1/x}-\log|x|\right)+2y_1'+y_1\log|x|=2y_1'
\end{align}
$$
Meaning
$$\mathcal L[y_2]=\mathcal L[y_1\log|x|+u_2]=\mathcal L[y_1\log|x|]+\mathcal L[u_2]=2y_1'+\mathcal L[u_2]$$